# Extensions for Adding Affiliate Javascript/Image-tracking to the Order Success Page

Tags: orders, affiliate

Are there any third party (open source or commercial) extensions that enable an better UI and/or a template interface for adding affiliate tracking code to the order success page?

That is, it's relatively easy for a PHP developer to gin up some code to add a block to Magento's order success page that will query the system for order information and generate specific javascript or `<img` tag based affiliate tracking code.

What I'm looking for is an extension that would allow a less technical user to accomplish the same task, either via a GUI or a template language that exposes the order variables in a flat, consistant way.

(I know how to approach building something like this — I want to know if something already exists that's relatively mature and stable)

Comment: Magento really needs a JS tracking "framework" where by providers can hook into with keys and attributes. Module developers currently reinvent the wheel with every new tracking module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a service that does it called [TagMan](http://www.tagman.com), but can be a real pain. The main issue we've noticed with this approach is that each vendor has different variables that they need, and some vendors need tracking on multiple pages with different tags. In the end, the only real advantage after all the headaches is that it's async. One of our clients had 27 tag vendors!

What we usually do is make a module that exposes blocks for each tag, that way we can consolidate some of the variables to not be calling something like total over and over. Anything static like account numbers goes in the admin.

Answer (score 2):

Another Tag Management option is QuBit's [OpenTag](http://www.opentag.qubitproducts.com/solution/); the basic versions are hosted and free.

They've got an open source version too but it lacks a front end (it's on GitHub).

They have an OpenTag [Magento Extension](https://github.com/QubitProducts/UniversalVariable-Magento-Extension) that implements their UniversalVariable *standard* which does some measure of normalising to make it simpler to pass the right information to the different tracking tools.

Answer (score 1):

Think this may be what you're looking for Alan -

http://magento.junowebdesign.com/generic-affiliate-tracking-code

I've had a lot of experience with Juno recently, and all very positive.